# jQuery pull div out of parent div

Tags: jquery, css

I have to div boxes on top of each other and I would like to hide the upper one if someone hovers over it.
HTML:

```
<div id="left_middle">
<div id="rfinder_UP"></div>
<div id="rfinder_DWN"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left_middle {
position:relative;
float: left;
width: 235px;
min-height: 220px;
background:green;
margin-right: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#rfinder_UP, 
#rfinder_DWN {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#rfinder_DWN{
background: url(images/rfinderapp_DWN.png) no-repeat;

}

#rfinder_UP {

    background: url(images/rfinderapp_UP.png) no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rfinder_UP").mouseover(function(){
  $("#rfinder_UP").hide();
  });
$("#rfinder_DWN").mouseout(function(){
  $("#rfinder_UP").show();
  });
});
```

Now I would like to achieve this by not only hiding the upper div with .hide but somehow pull it out of the left_middle div from the bottom. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried a lot of different other jQuery effects like animate, slideDown etc. but couldn't find a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

I have created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qEcp8/
The red box just disappears on hover revealing the black one. What I want is that the red one slides down, out of the left_middle box.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle with your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLdL8/) but it doesn't seem to be a starting point to help you out. Maybe you could modify it and your question would be easier to understand

Comment: I remove the Position fixed and top/left: 0, and it worked if i understand your problem right. When I hover the up. it does away and when i leave the Down It shows again.

Comment: It works when I just let it appear and disappears. What I am trying to achieve is that this works with an animation that pulls the upper div down and out of the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#rfinder_UP" ).hover(function() {

  $('#rfinder_DWN').animate({height:"100%"});
}, function() {
  $('#rfinder_DWN').animate({height:"0"});

}
);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EyVd6/1/

Please check whole code, i have changed your html and css accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#rfinder_UP:hover {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that one doesn't animate the fade out and doesn't work! http://jsfiddle.net/2UGLC/